# javascript alert() function not working in UWP app

Tags: javascript, html, alert, uwp

I used some little basic javascript code and used it to make a simple UWP app, the alert function in the code works when i run the file in the browser, but it doesnt work when i try it in UWP app. below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>App6</title>

<!-- WinJS references -->
<link href="WinJS/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="WinJS/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="WinJS/js/ui.js"></script>

<!-- App6 references -->
<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="win-type-body" onload="alert('oh yeah');">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check this, it might help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/73b5a412-aa1d-426c-b0e2-74df4eaac2a8/uwphosted-web-app?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: If you change the alert to output some text onto the page instead does it run? Maybe the uwp blocks alerts onload just like most pop up blockers do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alert function is not supported in UWP app context. You have to use

```
var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Hello");
dialog.showAsync();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208674?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1